# Presentation including today's date in beamer?

Tags: beamer, pdf

The challenge here it create a beamer presentation such that it would show the date in which it was used, not the day it was compiled.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  I compiled this presentation on \today, but I am presenting it today (\TODAY)!
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: You can probably do it by including some Javascript.

Comment: @lhf: This can _only_ be done with Javascript. And it then needs a PDF viewer that handles Javascript.