# how to autoupdate date on beamer pdf

Tags: beamer, datetime

It is not uncommon (at least for me ) to compile pdf a day before. It is also not uncommon to use same pdf on some other day. So it would be handy if pdf produced displays the system date on which it is being played rather than compilation date. Is it possible?

Comment: This would involve changing the `pdf` file itself, or you would have to use `JavaScript` to fill form fields. I do not know how to change it otherwise.

Comment: I remember that I have written once a `\tomorrow` command, which was a real hack.

Comment: Already asked here, but without an answer (except those in comments): [Presentation including today's date in beamer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154160/31416)

Comment: In a [similar question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14058/41085) the [`tdclock` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tdclock) was suggested as a solution. Behind the scenes, it uses JS like @Christian says.

Comment: tdclock seem to provide exceptable solution. Including clock is easy, but uses significant processor resources if the update time is less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just for the future visitors. tdclock package allows just what I expected. It only works with acrobat reader.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{madrid}
\usepackage[font=Times,timeinterval=10]{tdclock}
\title{Adding Current date}
\date{\tdclock}
\begin{document}
\initclock
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Ticking clock}\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you know the date you'll be showing the PDF, just include that date in the preamble:

```
\date{06/06/66}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not a real solution, but if you compile your document the day before, you can use following code to get a `\Tomorrow` command (please put it and the relevant packages into a separate `.sty` file if needed)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage{calculator}

\makeatletter


\newif\ifIsLeapYear\IsLeapYearfalse

\newcommand*{\YearIsLeapYear}[1]{%
\IsLeapYearfalse%
\MODULO{#1}{4}{\ModuloFourResult}%
\ifnumcomp{\ModuloFourResult}{=}{0}{%
\MODULO{#1}{100}{\ModuloOneHundredResult}%
   \ifnumcomp{\ModuloOneHundredResult}{=}{0}{%
\MODULO{#1}{400}{\ModuloFourHundredResult}%
   \ifnumcomp{\ModuloFourHundredResult}{=}{0}{%
      \IsLeapYeartrue%
}{%
      \IsLeapYearfalse%
}%
}{%
\IsLeapYeartrue% 
}}{\IsLeapYearfalse}%
}%




\newcounter{WorkSheet@@Day}%
\newcounter{WorkSheet@@Month}%
\newcounter{WorkSheet@@Year}%




\newcommand*{\WorkSheet@@SwitchToNextMonth}{%
  \setcounter{WorkSheet@@Day}{1}%
  \refstepcounter{WorkSheet@@Month}%
}%

\newcommand*{\WorkSheet@@SwitchToNextYear}{%
\setcounter{WorkSheet@@Day}{1}%
\setcounter{WorkSheet@@Month}{1}%
\refstepcounter{WorkSheet@@Year}%
}%

\newcommand*{\WorkSheetDayAfterDate}[3]{%
\setcounter{WorkSheet@@Day}{#1}%
\setcounter{WorkSheet@@Month}{#2}%
\setcounter{WorkSheet@@Year}{#3}%
%
\def\MonthsWithThirtyOneDays{1}%
\def\MonthsWithThirtyDays{4}%
%
%
\listadd{\MonthsWithThirtyOneDays}{1}%
\listadd{\MonthsWithThirtyOneDays}{3}%
\listadd{\MonthsWithThirtyOneDays}{5}%
\listadd{\MonthsWithThirtyOneDays}{7}%
\listadd{\MonthsWithThirtyOneDays}{8}%
\listadd{\MonthsWithThirtyOneDays}{10}%
\listadd{\MonthsWithThirtyOneDays}{12}%
%
\listadd{\MonthsWithThirtyDays}{4}%
\listadd{\MonthsWithThirtyDays}{6}%
\listadd{\MonthsWithThirtyDays}{9}%
\listadd{\MonthsWithThirtyDays}{11}%
\YearIsLeapYear{\number\value{WorkSheet@@Year}}%
\xifinlist{\number\value{WorkSheet@@Month}}{\MonthsWithThirtyOneDays}{%  It is a "long month"
%
\ifnumcomp{\value{WorkSheet@@Day}}{=}{31}{% Is the 31st day in the month!
% Check for 12/31/... 

\ifnumcomp{\value{WorkSheet@@Month}}{=}{12}{%
    \WorkSheet@@SwitchToNextYear}{ \WorkSheet@@SwitchToNextMonth}%
}{\refstepcounter{WorkSheet@@Day}}}{%

\ifnumcomp{\value{WorkSheet@@Month}}{=}{2}{% It is February
\ifnumcomp{\value{WorkSheet@@Day}}{=}{28}{% Is the 28th of February
\ifIsLeapYear%
\refstepcounter{WorkSheet@@Day}%
\else%
\WorkSheet@@SwitchToNextMonth%
\fi%
}{%
\ifIsLeapYear%
\ifnumcomp{\value{WorkSheet@@Day}}{=}{29}{% Is the 29th of February
\WorkSheet@@SwitchToNextMonth}{\refstepcounter{WorkSheet@@Day}}%
\else%
\refstepcounter{WorkSheet@@Day}%
\fi%
}}{%
% It is a month with 30 days!!
\xifinlist{\number\value{WorkSheet@@Month}}{\MonthsWithThirtyDays}{%
\ifnumcomp{\value{WorkSheet@@Day}}{=}{30}{% Is the 30st day in the month!
\WorkSheet@@SwitchToNextMonth}{\refstepcounter{WorkSheet@@Day}    

}}}{}%
}%
}%





\providecommand{\Tomorrow}{%
\WorkSheetDayAfterDate{\number\day}{\number\month}{\number\year}%
\newdate{DateOfTomorrow}{\number\value{WorkSheet@@Day}}{\number\value{WorkSheet@@Month}}{\number\value{WorkSheet@@Year}}%
\displaydate{DateOfTomorrow}
}%
\makeatother




\begin{document}
Tomorrow is \Tomorrow%
\end{document}
```

You can use the features of the `datetime` package in order to format the date according to your needs.

You still have to compile your document the day before, of course ;-)